# How do I stop Edge from taking over Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am working on a website and I need to test it in a real Internet Explorer. I have a Windows 10 computer with both Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge installed. When I open Internet Explorer, it switches over to Edge.

Initially, it would at least keep the Internet Explorer open. It would put some Microsoft.com help article into the tab instead of the website I requested, and it would open the website in Edge. Now it opens IE for a second and then forcibly closes it, then opens Edge.

##### What I tried

- First, I followed [the advice in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ONKtLL4Rik) to set "*Let Internet Explorer open sites in Microsoft Edge*" to "*Never*" (mine was actually called "*Do Not Allow*").

  That didn't help. Moreover, after the above, my IE is no longer staying open as the redirect happens
- Tried [creating `RedirectSitesFromInternetExplorerRedirectMode`](https://admx.help/?Category=EdgeChromium&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Edge::RedirectSitesFromInternetExplorerRedirectMode) in both `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

##### Versions

- Edge: 111.0.1661.41
- Windows 10 Pro: 21H2 19044.2604
- Windows Feature Experience Pack: 120.2212.4190.0

**UPD**

Someone in the comments asked "*I wonder why would you use an obsolete browser*" and here's one example someone posted in the answers, I will copy it here in case the answer gets deleted.

> This is one answer to the “Why use an obsolete browser like IE”. I am
> a HVAC Mechanic contractor service tech. There is a lot of “stand
> alone” HVAC equipment. To work on it we change our laptop settings to
> a static IP and connect local with an Ethernet cable and browser. This
> older equipment uses JAVA. None of the JAVA emulators have worked for
> me. Since it is not connected to the outside world there is no
> perceived risk from IE. Usable life span is measured in decades, so it
> will be around for the foreseeable future. Manufacturers stop any
> substantial updates after field proven reliability.
>
> PS if anyone has any ideas…: I am trying to connect to a Mitsubishi
> Citymulti GB-50 to see setup information (not stuff you can see with
> their Maintenance Tool program and interface tool). Will probably
> scrounge through my pile of tech junk and put together a Win 7 laptop
> that I won’t use on line.

Comment: Why not use a virtual machine with older Windows if it’s truly critical?

Comment: I wonder why would you use an obsolete browser but regardless, have you tried IE Mode? 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode

Comment: @Barreto - There is one website I used daily, one specific function, does not function properly within Chromium based browsers but does function properly with Internet Explorer.  So there might be a legitimate situation to use Internet Explorer, of course in my example, using IE Mode also works.

Comment: well there is legitimate situations to use IE, but I meant to work on new features. Why wouldn't you look for a way to make **your** website work on chromium based browsers? (since its widely used, not judging just curious)

Answer (score 8):

**Disclaimer:** you should not use IE for any other reason than historic research!

You can create vbs file with the following context (change `very-old-site.example.com` to your address)

```vb
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Navigate "very-old-site.example.com"
objIE.Visible = 1
```

When you run this file windows will open IE with URL, specified in vbs file. No additional steps required.

Checked on Windows 10 22H2, Edge 110.0.1587.69

Checked on Windows 10 22H2, Edge 120.0.2210.89 for any new Edge updates.

Comment: "you should not use IE for any other reason than historic research". Or if your old security system (or whatever) only works with IE. In theory, Edge IE Mode *should* work (because it actually uses IE) but apparently there are cases where it doesn't (maybe where plugins are involved).

Comment: IE is the only browser with built-in [Element source with style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911338/tools-to-selectively-copy-htmlcssjs-from-a-specific-element-of-dom/14664803#14664803) option to copy markup and CSS of an HTML element.

Answer (score 5):

To prevent Edge from hijacking Internet Explorer, you will need to deactivate the Internet Explorer plugin that is forcefully installed by Edge. To do that, please follow the below instructions with administrative privileges:

1. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\<a.b.c.d version>` directory
2. Locate a subfolder named `BHO`
3. Rename the `BHO` subfolder to `BHO.bak`

Now, when you start Internet Explorer (`IExplore.exe`) it will not be overtaken by Edge.

Please note that this is a hack which should not be used for anything real except testing or playing with historical artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

You can just rename these files to disabled.
[image: disable-BHO edge]

close iexplore and re-open

Comment: I did this and suddenly today it stopped working and my changes disappeared. Don't know if Edge was updated or a restart caused it. Instead of renaming, I tried to provide a fake file with same name in its place. Unfortunately I am not able to test if it works, because I found another solution in the meantime [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1773737/how-do-i-stop-edge-from-taking-over-internet-explorer/1787548#1787548).

Comment: Maybe your edge version is different? you might need to restart your device too.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a website in Edge IE Mode it actually uses Internet Explorer in the background (you will see iexplore.exe in the task list) so most IE-specific pages will work in IE Mode. Sometimes all that's needed to get an old page working in IE Mode is to set the Compatibility view (which indeed can be set for Edge IE Mode).

However, some people have reported that they cannot get Edge IE mode to work with their old camera, security system, company website, etc. I can't confirm those claims, but there are many possible variables, including plugins.

Another reason to use an Internet Explorer launcher, instead of Edge IE Mode, is to avoid the 30 day timeout on IE Mode pages (or avoid applying workarounds, such as [IEModeExpiryFix](https://lesferch.github.io/IEModeExpiryFix/)).

To run IE directly, as already noted, it can be done easily with a simple script. But a launcher Exe, such as **[LaunchIE](https://lesferch.github.io/LaunchIE/)** is simpler and slicker, especially when it comes to making shortcuts.

Comment: LaunchIE worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Search for "Internet Options" or open it from Control Panel.
There, in the "Advanced" tab, disable option `Enable third-party browser extensions`.

I am not sure what else does it disable, but so far it looks promising on my machine.

[image: Internet Properties]

Comment: Why do you believe this will allow the author to continue to use Internet Explorer, if it was already disabled, a few months ago through a Microsoft Edge update. This option doesn’t do what you think it does

Comment: This worked for me as of August 11, 2023. Yes, we shouldn't be using internet explorer anymore, but heck if I can do anything about the ancient applications that my employer is chained to

Answer (score -2):

Just delete the 3 programs in the BHO folder.
Send the BHO folder to the desk top (create shortcut) with a right mouse click .
Check the BHO folder before using IE if the short cut is invalid you got an Edge update repeat step 1 .

Comment: Which BHO folder? Please make sure your answers are **as specific as possible**.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).