# Force Internet Explorer 11 to open instead of Edge on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, group-policy

I know IE11 is retired and not advisable to use BUT I need it.

We have a test lab (closed off to the internet) for some Windows 10 PCs (for legacy applications), running Windows 10 Enterprise version 21H2.

After installing October Windows patches:

https://support.microsoft.com/help/5031356

https://support.microsoft.com/help/5031539

We now have an issue where shortcuts that usually open with IE11 now open up Microsoft Edge. We had similar issue earlier this year where upgrading the version of Edge caused this issue. After some searching on forums we put a fix in place via the group policy.

The details of the GPO are:

[image: GPO Details]

I know there is option to use IE mode with MS edge (currently trying to get this setup also).

I have tried Rename the BHO Folder, modify Internet Options (unticking option "Enable third-party browser extensions"), default browser is already set to IE11, setting in Edge "Let Internet Explorer open sites in Microsoft Edge" is set to "Never" and unable to uninstall Edge as we use that also.

I have also tried the below command in CMD.exe doesn't work either:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" https://some.webiste.com
```

**Edge version we are running is 92.0.902.84 (Official build) (64-bit)**

I have solution via Stack Exchange from user markalex (thanks!)

You can create vbs file with the following context (change very-old-site.example.com to your address):

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Navigate "very-old-site.example.com"
objIE.Visible = 1
```

Which works for each URL defined in the vbs script.

Please let me know if there is another setting or tweak I could use to get desktop shortcuts opening in IE11 thanks guys!

Comment: This question belongs on [su] instead, as it is an OS-related question and not a programming question.

Comment: You probably should setup a Docker image to run something like Windows 7 as a VM for better security and control... Getting legacy web browsers to run by default on your computer is not a good idea.

Comment: [Similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1773737/how-do-i-stop-edge-from-taking-over-internet-explorer "How do I stop Edge from taking over Internet Explorer?")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unselecting "Enable third-party browser extensions" option had worked but does not work anymore.

[KB5031355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5031355-cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-october-10-2023-c56fd2d7-64c5-4883-8614-b745b7325530) (Windows Server, October 10, 2023) notices that "certain versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer have reached end of servicing".

Therefore, the simplest solution may be uninstalling [KB5031356](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/october-10-2023-kb5031356-os-builds-19044-3570-and-19045-3570-951fac64-5bf8-4eba-ba18-a9448920df1a) (Windows 10, October 10, 2023) and then unselecting "Enable third-party browser extensions" option.

---

On the other hand, as you wrote, you can use a VBS or PowerShell script for opening Internet Explorer, instead of redirecting to Edge.

- VBS Script

  1. Create `.vbs` file with the script below.
  2. Run VBS file.
  3. Internet Explorer will be started (but will not go to foreground).

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "about:blank"
ie.Visible = 1
```

- PowerShell script

  1. Create `.bat` file with the script below.
  2. Run BAT file.
  3. Internet Explorer will be started.

```
@PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application -Property @{Navigate2='about:blank'; Visible=1}
```

`@PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass` is also possible.

If you want to pin the batch file to taskbar or start menu, create a shortcut with the following script instead of the above BAT file.

`cmd /c "@PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application -Property @{Navigate2='about:blank'; Visible=1}"`

Note that `InPrivate` browsing seems to be impossible under these methods. `InPrivate` browsing was possible by `iexplore.exe -private about:blank`, which does not work anymore.

---

Some articles in Chinese web report that IE can be re-enabled by replacing the following files with old ones.

- `C:\Windows\System32\ieframe.dll`
- `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ieframe.dll`

You can try this method if you are not satisfied with the script-based method.

[KB5031356](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/october-10-2023-kb5031356-os-builds-19044-3570-and-19045-3570-951fac64-5bf8-4eba-ba18-a9448920df1a) (Windows 10, October 10, 2023) comes with the `11.0.19041.3570` version of `ieframe.dll`. Prior versions may be needed for this method.

Comment: Just tested the .bat file with script you provided and works fine thanks for you help on this! Unfortunately we cant uninstall the updates and at this current moment I don't want to be replacing files within the C:\Windows and we don't require inprivate browsing at this moment just happy that there are alternative methods of accessing IE11 now.

Comment: Do you have an idea what version of `ieframe.dll` should be used to restore IE?

Comment: @user9564371 To my knowledge, `11.0.19041.3393` or older one is required. You can search corresponding information with the keywords "KB5031356 ieframe.dll".